# Get OpenVPN client IP script

Tags: ip, openvpn, shell-scripting

My machine get's an IP from OpenVPN server when connecting to the VPN gateway. This is tun0 on Ubuntu. I assume naming might be different for other systems that may connect to OpenVPN gateway.

Is that a reliable way (a script) to determine an IP, that was given to a machine by VPN gateway?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to specify an `up` script, which will receive the `ifconfig_local` and `ifconfig_remote` environment variables, which contain the local and remote IP addresses assigned to the VPN tunnel.

You'll also need to set `script-security 2` in order to have your script actually run.